# Dynamic repetition of words of a cell

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Hi there I build a database in Google Sheets and have the following problem.
I have three values: Date, employee and task.
In the end I need for all combinations one line.

Goal:

Because the number of employees and tasks can change by time, I need to build this by formula.

[image: target state]

The only missing formula is in the red cell, which repeats the tasks as many times, as there are employees. So every employe has each date with each task.

[image: now]

How do I do that?

Here the link to the google sheet to copy and test:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O0bpQJWAncpU-g-93wACa9QHXpFP0SX7snQc3p6gcpA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE(DAYS(F3,F2)+1,1,F2,1)&"|"&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(I2:I,I2:I<>"")))&"|"&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(H2:H,H2:H<>""))),"|"))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: woow, that's next level!